# What exception would google app engine return if tried to add data in datastore that is already full

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What exception would google app engine return if tried to add data in datastore that is already full?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be an `apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError` as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted).